# Temporarily switch window contexts

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an .net mvc application that has the possibility of being in an iframe of another application. This application makes calls to a third party that opens windows and interacts with the user before returning a “result”. The problem is that when this application is in an iframe the windows this third party opens are blocked because of iframe security policy. I would like to either send the necessary data via the C# equivalent of window.postMessage and have the parent application handle the event and temporarily do the third party interactions in the context of the parent before returning the “results” or somehow just temporarily switching context so the third party interactions are not blocked. The first method of using window.postMessage seems like it works but temporarily operating in JavaScript is cumbersome. The second method I am really unfamiliar with and would need some sample to show how I would recognize that the .net MVC application is in an iframe and how to switch contexts when it is. What is the best method?